# Laravel excel: Excel::create equivalent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-excel

I'm trying to use this component, I've updated it from 2.1 to 3.1 and my exports now are broken the method `create` doesnt exist in this new version or there's something that I'm missing in the documentation.

```
 Excel::create()

Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()
```

Comment: You're [not missing anything](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html). Upgrade guide says that these methods are removed. Exportables are now the preferred method. The library is vastly different now. I encourage you to go through the documentation about it.

Comment: I've reading it but i dont see a part that talks about cells manipulation https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/cells.html, something like `$sheet->row` we used to use

Answer (score 0):

Here the docs https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/
You have to create a export class inside de folder:

> app/Exports/

with this command:

> php artisan make:export UsersExport --model=User

Will be create the file UsersExport.php

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
  public function collection()
  {
    return User::all();
  }
}
```

In your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

In your route

```
Route::get('users/export/', 'UsersController@export');
```

Comment: How can i manipulate the cells in this new version? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/cells.html

Comment: @Christian You would now be using [Concerns](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/concerns.html). Such as, [adding a heading row](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#adding-a-heading-row)

Answer (score -2):

export data in excel using laravel plugin

Excel::create('filename', function($excel) use ($data){

```
    $excel->sheet('filename', function($sheet) use ($data){
    $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
    $sheet->cell('A1:Z1', function ($cells) {
            $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
        });
    $sheet->setWidth('A', 5);
    $sheet->cell('A1:A', function($cells) {
            $cells->setAlignment('center');
        });
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```